# Where do you store your configurations? Dockerfiles, gitlab-ci, application.properties, deploy scripts

Tags: configuration-management

Let´s suppose that our repository contents is something that will be shared. Is strange that we include the deploy scripts there, explaining how to deploy in our machines

Answer (score 1):

If by "Shared" you mean that your team has access to the files then it should be stored in Source Control so that everyone on the team is using the same scripts.  You can consider a secrets manager so that team members do not share sensitive information (e.g., [Docker Secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/), [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-secrets-manager-store-distribute-and-rotate-credentials-securely/), [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/)).

If this will be publicly available you can still use a secrets manager to publish these files with the sensitive data removed.

Comment: It will be shared with different clients